# Why was the Astraeus never relaunched?

Tags: eureka

In *Eureka*, after the crew of the *Astraeus* is rescued, they still have the ship and all the equipment they had previously.  The crew is trained, and, other than one member, they're all still available.

Considering the expense put into the mission in the first place, and that everything needed was still available, and that a minimal amount of additional training (including a debriefing of the whole matrix thing) would be needed to keep the crew in prime condition, is there a good reason why they didn't just re-launch the mission?

Why was it just abandon and the ship and the transport technology ignored?  This was the town's big focus for a long time, so to just drop it once they rescue the crew doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: There were so many story lines in that show that just got dropped. Remember when Jack married Allison in an alternate time line?

Comment: @Sam: I don't have a problem with alternate timeline plots being dropped - sometimes they just give us a peek at something that might or will be.  But dropping a major plot point like this begs explanation.

Comment: The non-cannon answer would likely be the show was done. The point of the trip, was just to drive the story to the conspiracy.

Comment: It would take years of government investigation and paperwork to deal with the aftermath before another mission would be authorized and funded.

Answer (score 5):

After the "Challenger" disaster, the US put their Human Space Flight programme on 'hold' for almost two years while they conducted an [extensive investigation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers_Commission_Report). It seems likely that within the Eureka Universe they would have had the same sorts of inquests into the [Astraeus](http://eureka.wikia.com/wiki/The_Real_Thing) programme to determine a) what happened and b) how to prevent it happening again.

On top of that, it then became apparent that [enemies of the US](http://eureka.wikia.com/wiki/Beverly_Barlowe) had had total access to the designs, schematics and prototypes for the ship and had intentionally sabotaged the blueprints from the ground upwards.

If you found that your spaceship had been **deliberately designed to crash**, you'd probably want to cannibalise the original for parts and start right over at the testing stage rather than sticking more people in it to see what happens next.

[image]

My personal guess it they probably would have returned to it once the sixth season had been confirmed. Or maybe not. Frankly, that show threw up Earth-shattering inventions on a weekly basis and then just as quickly forgot about them.